# How to escape escaped regex characters when using Rust's regex crate?

Tags: regex, rust, escaping

I have a regex that has many `"` and `\` escaped characters. I tested my regex in general and you can find [my working live demo](https://regex101.com/r/7giQd7/1). I transferred the regex to Rust. Here is a simplified example that does not work:

```
extern crate regex; // 1.1.0
use regex::Regex;

fn main() {
    let re = Regex::new(r#"123 \\""(\w+)"#).unwrap();
    let test = "123 \"PROPFIND\"";

    for cap in re.captures_iter(test) {
        println!("{}", &cap[1]);
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c65250d50999755a9047d3f40e4c72b8)

The output of my example is empty, but I expect `PROPFIND`

The regex documentation pointed me to the [raw string](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/tokens.html#raw-string-literals) documentation. I played around with different escaping techniques, but can't figure out where I messed up.

Comment: What happens when you reduce your regex to *just* test for one thing, such as the IP address or any other one piece?  See [MCVE].

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I'll try match for match to trace down the problem.

Comment: You don't need to escape quotes in raw string, use your inputs like this:  [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4e8256b9610ab7962fb9b8c7f67a91d8)

Comment: Note that `(HTTP|HTTPS)` = `(HTTPS?)` in the pattern and the dot between digits must be escaped to match a literal dot.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for hint.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your original pattern needs to be written as

```
let re = Regex::new(r#"(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}) (\w+|-) (\w+|-) \[(.*?)\] "(\w+) (.*?) (HTTPS?)/([0-9]\.[0-9])" ([0-9]+) ([0-9]+) "(\w+|-)" "(.*?)""#).unwrap();
```

The current one as:

```
let re = Regex::new(r#"123 "(\w+)""#).unwrap();
```

In short, all `\\""` in your pattern should look like `"`. And make sure the pattern is inside `r#"` and `"#`.

Please refer to the [Rust raw string literals reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/tokens.html#raw-string-literals):

> Raw string literals do not process any escapes. They start with the character `U+0072` (`r`), followed by zero or more of the character `U+0023` (`#`) and a `U+0022` (double-quote) character. The *raw string body* can contain any sequence of Unicode characters and is terminated only by another `U+0022` (double-quote) character, followed by the same number of `U+0023` (`#`) characters that preceded the opening `U+0022` (double-quote) character.

Comment: My problem was in general I didn't understand that I've to remove the regular regex escapes as well. But now I got it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @createproblem `\w` is a regex escape and you should not remove it. Doubles quotes are not special and should not be regex-escaped. Also, you actually doubled the double quotes in the pattern, hence there was no chance it could find a match.